# How to convert from a string to a float when taking the data from excel

Tags: python, matplotlib

I imported data from an excel sheet, only reading the first two rows. Whenever I try to run the code my error is that it could not convert from string to float. Is there any way to fix this? My code is below.

```
%matplotlib notebook 
import numpy as np                           
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

file = 'Cepheid_proj.csv'
Cepheid1 = np.loadtxt(file, skiprows=1) 

fig= plt.figure()                            
plt.title('Luminosity vs Period\n') 
axes=fig.add_subplot(111)                    
plt.ylabel('Luminosity (W)')    
plt.xlabel('Period (days)')            
plt.xlim((44500.0,46000.0))      
plt.ylim((9.0,12.0))
axes.plot(Cepheid1[:,0], Cepheid1[:,1], label='Ca ces')

plt.legend(loc=1, prop={'size': 7})          
plt.show()
```

Comment: float(Cepheid1[:,0])

Comment: Do note: Just because you use M$ Excel to open a file does not make it an Excel file. Excel files are .xls, .xlsx etc. Yours is just a CSV (comma separated values) file

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
import csv
import numpy
output = csv.reader(open("Cepheid_proj.csv", "rb"), delimiter=",")
x = list(output)
float_output = numpy.array(x).astype("float")
```

If this source code not work then take a look at the next steps:

1.You have an CVS file , read how to used it, see [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

2.Using numpy you need to use something like that:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
csv_data = genfromtxt('Cepheid_proj.csv', delimiter=',')
```

3.Try read about *Python Data Type Conversion* , see [this link](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-data-type-conversion)